# Convert a map of maps into single list of values in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, stream

I have a Map of map :

```
Map<Integer,Map<String,Integer>>
```

I need this map to be flattened into just the list of values :

```
Map<String,Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String,Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map1.putIfAbsent("ABC",123);
map1.putIfAbsent("PQR",345);
map1.putIfAbsent("XYZ",567);
map2.putIfAbsent("ABC",234);
map2.putIfAbsent("FGH",789);
map2.putIfAbsent("BNM",890);
Map<Integer,Map<String,Integer>> mapMap = new HashMap();
mapMap.putIfAbsent(0,map1);
mapMap.putIfAbsent(1,map2);
```

Expected output :
123

345

567

234

789

890

I need different solution including java 8 streams!!

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your *non-stream* attempt?

Comment: What trouble are you having when you're using streams to create the list of values?  Please include in your question any code you have so far, along with any error messages, exception stack traces, or incorrect output you may have.  Your post so far indicates that you expect a solution to be written for you.

Comment: Exactly!! I was clueless about the approach using streams. The below solution is what i was looking for : @rgettman,

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose : Not clear about what exactly you meant to cleared!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect all number values using:

```
List<Integer> numbers = mapMap
     .values() //all `Map` values
     .stream()
     .map(Map::values) //map each inner map to the collection of its value
     .flatMap(Collection::stream) // flatten all inner value collections
     .collect(Collectors.toList()); //collect all values into a single list
```

`numbers` contains `[345, 123, 567, 890, 234, 789]` in the above code

Comment: Thanks for the approch. This what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 List<Integer> result= new ArrayList<>();
 mapMap.forEach((key, value) -> result.addAll(value.values()));
```